# The additive property of mutual information

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, information-theory

Let $X,Y_1,Y_2$ be three random variables. Let $I(X;Y)$ denote the mutual information of $X,Y$. My question: Does the inequality $I(X;Y_1,Y_2) \le I(X;Y_1)+I(X;Y_2) $ hold? Or, in what condition, does it hold?

Answer (score 2):

$$I(X;Y_1,Y_2)=H(Y_1,Y_2)-H(Y_1,Y_2|X)=H(Y_1)+H(Y_2)-I(Y_1;Y2)-H(Y_1,Y_2|X)$$

$$I(X;Y_1)=H(Y_1)-H(Y_1|X)$$
$$I(X;Y_2)=H(Y_2)-H(Y_2|X)$$
Thus
$$\begin{align}
I(X;Y_1,Y_2)-\left(I(X;Y_1)+I(X;Y_2)\right)&=H(Y_1|X)+H(Y_2|X)-I(Y_1;Y2)-H(Y_1,Y_2|X)\\
&=I(Y_1;Y_2|X)-I(Y_1;Y_2)
\end{align}$$
But $I(Y_1;Y_2|X)-I(Y_1;Y_2)$ which is called [interaction information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information#Properties) can be positive, negative, or zero.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information#Example_of_Positive_Interaction_Information) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information#Example_of_Negative_Interaction_Information) for more information on positive and negative interaction information.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Furthermore, I have a confusion: Is the notation $I(X;Y_1;Y_2)$ denoted in wikipedia  the same as the  $I(X;Y_1,Y_2)$?

Comment: $I(X;Y;Z)$ is the gray area in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VennInfo3Var.svg) Venn diagram. However, $I(X,Y;Z)$ is regions yellow, gray and cyan together.

Answer (score 2):

From the chain rule property of mutual information, it holds

$$
\begin{align}
I(X;Y_1, Y_2)&=I(X;Y_1)+I(X;Y_2|Y_1)\\
&\leq I(X;Y_1)+I(X;Y_2),
\end{align}
$$

where the inequality holds only if

$$
I(X;Y_2|Y_1) \leq I(X;Y_2) \tag{1}
$$

Note that $(1)$ does not hold in general (as also noted my @msm). One case where it does hold is when the variables form a Markov chain of the form $Y_1\rightarrow X \rightarrow Y_2$, i.e., it holds

$$
p(y_1,x,y_2)=p(y_1)p(x|y_1)p(y_2|x).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Furthermore, I have a confusion: Is the notation $I(X;Y_1;Y_2)$ denoted in wikipedia  the same as the  $I(X;Y_1,Y_2)$?

Comment: @Epsilon $I(X;Y;Z)$ corresponds to the [multivariate mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information) (MI), which is an attempt to generalize the standard MI definition that involves two (vector) variables $I(X;Y,Z)$. These two definitions are in no way related and should not be confused.